# Fixing WebSocket 404 Error With Dynamic WebSocket URL's Under Reverse Proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy, socket

I am running Ubuntu, Apache, mod_proxy_wstunnel(Enabled), Shiny-Server, and R. I have setup shiny-server to listen locally, and Apache to Proxy requests for the shiny-server. I have also setup a basic authorization in my Apache config for the entire domain.

Everything is fine except for when the shiny-server application tries to make a Web Socket Request. I receive the following error.

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxxxx.com/shiny-application/__sockjs__/407/ercpnzw1/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 401
```

I would normally just add what the exact URL for the Web Socket is but, this sock.js url in dynamic, and always changes.

Is there a way to resolve this issue with a regex in apache config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this issue, most likely caused by Reverse Proxy with Shiny-server and Apache. Add the disable_websockets true; as shown below. **NOTE: ** This seems to only work with newer versions of Shiny-Server (Shiny Server Professional v1.2.0 i believe).

```
# Define the user we should use when spawning R Shiny processes
run_as shiny;

disable_websockets true;

# Define a top-level server which will listen on a port
server {
  # Instruct this server to listen on port 3838
  listen 3838;

  # Define the location available at the base URL
  location / {
    #### PRO ONLY ####
    # Only up tp 20 connections per Shiny process and at most 3 Shiny processes
    # per application. Proactively spawn a new process when our processes reach 
    # 90% capacity.
    utilization_scheduler 20 .9 3;
    #### END PRO ONLY ####

    # Run this location in 'site_dir' mode, which hosts the entire directory
    # tree at '/srv/shiny-server'
    site_dir /srv/shiny-server;

    # Define where we should put the log files for this location
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;

    # Should we list the contents of a (non-Shiny-App) directory when the user 
    # visits the corresponding URL?
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```